# Twig input type time in 24H format

Tags: twig

I use Symfony and Twig for my front end. How to make in input to be in 24h not in am and pm

[image: 24hformat]

Date





Time

This is my form build

```
    $builder
        ->add('date', DateType::class,
            [
                'widget'=>'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm',
            ])
}


public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=>---::class
        ));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`date`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html) filter in Twig? `{{ "now"|date("H:i") }}` where `H` represents 24 hour with leading zero. `i` represents minutes with leading zeroes.

Comment: I was play with this and when add in value show me 02:04, but if I remove type="time" give me 14:00 how should be, but then I don't have drop down option to choice another time.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`DateTimeType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#hours) instead of `DateType`:

```
->add('date', DateTimeType::class,
        [
            'widget'=>'single_text',
        ])
```

Comment: I did, but is the same. Should I change now in twig file something to show 24h.